# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document in Windows Phone 8.1 phonegap apps

Tags: javascript, c#, debugging, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I'm currently developing Windows Phone 8.1 app using Phonegap/Cordova plugins and Windows Runtime Component.

When I put breakpoints and start to debug on Runtime Component in VS 2013 Community Edition I got this message

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

I'm debugging on my Windows Phone 8.1 device (not Emulator).

Also I have set the Debugger type to Managed and Debugger Launcher to device, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

I think you asked the same question in MSDN forum.

We cannot directly debug the windows runtime component project in Cordova project at least for now. It's a little complicated.

As a workaround, we can use the generated winjs project to debug the windows runtime component project. Please check my latest reply in [the same MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5781b132-1387-4bc9-8a58-fce122f528d4/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-document?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova&prof=required).

If anyone else want to the same in Visual Studio 2015, to find the winjs solution, go to "\platforms\windows".